# "An unknown error occurred" when loggin in in Visual Studio 2013 SPA template on IIS8 express

Tags: iis-8, visual-studio-templates, visual-studio-2013

I have used the SPA template in VS2013 and try to host it in IIS8 on Win8.
When I try to Log In in the Todo list I get a `An unknown error occurred.`

When I run the solution in VS2013 (preview v.12.0.20623.01 update) through the development webserver it runs alright.
But I want to use the real IIS and hence created an application in IIS8express for the same folder.
When I try to register or log in to the todo list I get the error above.

Running aspnet development on the IIS is no problem, I have done it for years.
Looking through the code it looks like it has something to do with the Identity providers, like the code cannot enumerate them when running in IIS. I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Nuclear option. Could you try upgrading from vs 2013 preview upto visual studio 2013 rc (release candidate)? Then try using that IIS EXPRESS on the web project settings tab?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for login in is `/api/AjaxAccount/Login`. When using an application in IIS the application name looks like a sub folder like so `localhost/myapp`. This messes up the URL that tries to go to `localhost/api/AjaxAccount/Login` instead of `localhost/myapp/api/AjaxAccount`.

I see two immediate solutions to this.
1) make `loginURL` in `self.login = function( user )` in file `app.datamodel.js` receive the correct URL (i.e. patch the code somewhere).
2) reconfigure IIS and possibly hack the hosts file to handle `myproj.myuniqueurl.com`

I did change the URL by hacking it in the debugger but was then greeted with a 500 instead. But that is another Q/A yet to be told.